# Why my android program works fine on 4.4.3 version but doesnt work on 10.0

Tags: java, android

On the phone string is empty, why thats happend? 
Phone is android version 10, nox is 4.4.3 if thats matters?

I try more codes for read web page but result is same, i dont know why its happend?

```
class GetData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        String result = "";
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://www.b92.net/info/rss/sport.xml");
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            int code = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

            if(code==200){
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                if (in != null) {
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                    String line = "";

                    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                        result += line;
                }
                in.close();
            }

            return result;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        finally {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return result;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        tv.setText(result);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Any error or exception ?

Comment: Nope just displays blank TextView, its weird because on Nox works perfectly...

Comment: `https://www.b92.net/info/rss/sport.xml` . Use `https` instead of `http`.

Comment: See: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/04/protecting-users-with-tls-by-default-in.html

Comment: WOW, works. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To turn @intellij-amiya s comment into an answer:

> Use https instead of http: https://www.b92.net/info/rss/sport.xml

this [blog post](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/04/protecting-users-with-tls-by-default-in.html) tells us that clear-traffic is (basically) forbidden now (as @morrison-chang pointed out)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Internet Permission in Manifest.